# How to mix Python code into a Python extension module

Tags: python, package, setup.py, pybind11

Say I have a Python package `mymodule` based on a Pybind11 extension where the following code works like a charm after running `python setup.py install`:

```
from mypackage.subA import foo  # foo is written in C++.
from mypackage.subB import bar  # Same for bar.
```

I now want to add some pure Python code in one of the submodules, say `subA`, so that I can also do

```
from mypackage.subA import pure_python_func
```

[I've made an MCVE of such a project](https://www.github.com/bsamseth/DummyExtension)  to hopefully make this as clear as possible.

If I add a file `mypackage/subA.py` in which I write `pure_python_func` (and add an empty `mypackage/__init__.py`), I can import the Python part, but the extension module disappears. I.e.

```
from mypackage.subA import pure_python_func  # Works
from mypackage.subA import foo  # Fails
from mypackage.subB import bar  # Fails
```

My question is how can I end up with a something that has both extension code *and* Python code within the same package? Preferably within the same submodules, but at least within the same package. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to build your C++ module into a protected module outside of your public module, and import this protected module into your public module.

For example, change `mypackage.subA.foo` to build to `_mypackage._foo`. Then the file `mypackage/subA/__init__.py` would look something like this:

```py
from _mypackage._foo import *
from mypackage.subA._pythonModule import *

# Any other python code could be imported here as well
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but the issue was that as soon as I added `mypackage/__init__.py` then I could no longer import from the extension module. I think it shadowed the extension module because they were named the same. I'm thinking this is fixable in `setup.py`, but I can't seem to make it work - do you know how it should look to make your suggestion work?

Comment: answer updated. I had done this so long ago that I had forgotten that would happen.

Comment: That works! Thought I had tried that before, but turns out I forgot to change the name in the CMakeLists.txt file as well as in setup.py and the Pybind11 code. Thanks a lot!